# Bootstrap navbar not placing the items correctly

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="">DELIVER</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
        <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0">
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">PANDA</a>
          </li>
          
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
              {{ request.user.username }}
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">個人檔案</a></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">我的訂單</a></li>
              <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
              <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">登出</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          
        </ul>
        <form class="d-flex">
          <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search items" aria-label="Search">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
        </form>
      </div>
     
    </div>
</nav>
```

For the above code, I would like to put the navbar items on the right. However I had already tried `me-auto` and `mr-auto` but all the items are still put on the left. Even though I followed the documentation of Bootstrap it still didn't work. Can anyone tell me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To align navbar (place it on right), just add **".justify-content-end"** to **".collapse"** block, see Code snipper comment.

To check it in Code Snippet example you might need to open it in full screen.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-zCbKRCUGaJDkqS1kPbPd7TveP5iyJE0EjAuZQTgFLD2ylzuqKfdKlfG/eSrtxUkn" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">DELIVER</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    
    <!-- add "justify-content-end" here -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarSupportedContent">
      <!-- remove unnecessary "me-auto" -->
      <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link" href="#">PANDA</a>
        </li>

        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">{{ request.user.username }}</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">個人檔案</a></li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">我的訂單</a></li>
            <li>
              <hr class="dropdown-divider">
            </li>
            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">登出</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>

      </ul>
      <form class="d-flex">
        <input class="form-control me-2" type="search" placeholder="Search items" aria-label="Search">
        <button class="btn btn-outline-success" type="submit">Search</button>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happen because the navbar-collapse are given display flex. And flexing default properties are pulling the items left and right.
To pull the navbar-items to the right just remove the "me-auto" class from unordered-list. and add the flex properties class  "justify-content-end" with the "navbar-collapse" class.

[image]